# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts in docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

i'm running my asp.net core application through systemd and nginx on linux and it works fine. I have tried to run it through a docker container but i'm getting an error when i use docker run -p 5000:5000 name-of-repo : `Application startup exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

which is weird because running through systemd or dotnet run doesnt give this error and the application works just fine. Am i missing some configuration in docker or something?

here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT docker

ENTRYPOINT dotnet run
```